# JSON serialization not working in WCF Rest services

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, service, web

I`am trying to implement basic rest service using WCF and I forced with the problem of JSON serialization. In my service Interface I define next method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Book/{id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
Book GetBookById(string id);
```

When I uses WebMessageFormat.Xml everything works fine, but when I change response format to JSON I`am get nothing (just empty html page).

And I don't know why this happens? I must be missed something.

Maybe I should show my code for more details. It`s my service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IBookService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Book/{id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Book GetBookById(string id);
    }
```

and it`s my implementation:

```
public class BookService : IBookService
    {
        public Book GetBookById(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                int bookId = Convert.ToInt32(id);

                using (BookContext entities = new BookContext())
                {
                    return entities.BookSet.FirstOrDefault(book => book.Id == bookId);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new FaultException("Something went wrong");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you pass a wrong book id and your method returns null?

Comment: No, it`s excluded. I just tested it 1 sec ago

Comment: Can you use a REST client, like fiddler or an add in for chrome or firefox and let us what the response returns (header information, like status code)

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not HTML. If JSON is fed into an HTML renderer, it won't render anything on screen.  Use an HTTP request sniffer like Fiddler to look at the response in its native encoding.  You could also try View Page Source in the browser.

Comment: I tried to view page Source in my browser but I`am getting just empty page when I used JSON serialization.

Comment: When I uses Fiddler Web Debugger I also dont get a response

Comment: If you're using localhost in your URL (server and client are on the same machine) change localhost to the machine's network IP address.  Fiddler can't proxy localhost connections because localhost shortcuts the network stack.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps can help you :

**Contract for json service:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceJson {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Book/{id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Book GetBookById(string id);
}
```

**Implementation :**

```
public class ServiceImplementation : IServiceJson {
  Book GetBookById(string id) {
    // Implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have the same implementation [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBookService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Book/{id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Book GetBookById(string id);

}

Comment: Moving that attributes to an interface won't change anything.